# vector<bool> specialization incompatible with range base for

Tags: c++, c++11

I cant get the following snippet to compile with g++ or clang

```
void foo(vector<bool>& p)
{
    for( auto& b : p )
        b=true;
}
```

I know there is / used to be `vector<bool>` specialization. 
Is this a known bug? Or does standard give exception to that case? 
Or am I missing something simple?

g++ gives me the following:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type std::_Bit_reference
from an rvalue of type std::_Bit_iterator::reference {aka std::_Bit_reference}
```

clang gives:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::_Bit_reference' cannot bind to a
temporary of type 'reference' (aka 'std::_Bit_reference')
```

Comment: what compile error are you getting?

Comment: It's not a bug. The proxy class is returned as a temporary. Use `auto&&` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` returns a temporary proxy object when the iterators are dereferenced. That means that you have to use either `auto`, `auto&&` or `const auto&` but not `auto&` because you can't bind a temporary value to a non-const l-value reference.

For example, this works and will print all `1`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<bool>& p)
{
    for(auto&& b : p) {
        b = true;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> p = { true, false, true, true };
    foo(p);
    for(const auto& b : p) {
        std::cout << b << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d0653f695dcccb8)